# How to fix this Ansible error for most of the modules?

Tags: ansible

I had to format the mac and after re-installing everything I get errors in one of my Ansible projects
(no code was changed. It might be that some tool is missing or is different ansible version)

Take this example script

```
- name: ensure that ~/.ssh/config.d folder exists
  file:
    path=~/.ssh/config.d
    recurse=yes
    state=directory
```

I get this error

```
TASK [deploy : ensure that ~/.ssh/config.d folder exists] ***********
fatal: [dockerall -> 127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: /Users/k/Library/Application: No such file or directory\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}
```

I get exactly this same error for `lineinfile` and many other modules no matter what I try.

I believe some tool is not installed as the /Library/Application is not mentioned anywhere and I have no clue.

I am using Mac Sonoma 14.3.1

The ansible version is

```
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.3]
  config file = /Users/k/deploy/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/k/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/k/Library/Application Support/pipx/venvs/ansible/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/k/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Users/k/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.12.2 (main, Feb  6 2024, 20:19:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)] (/Users/k/Library/Application Support/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True
```

Can you please give me any help on how to trobuleshoot this further so I know how to fix ?

I installed ansible using the documentation here
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#pipx-install

```
pipx install --include-deps ansible
```

Comment: Seems to happen because of the space in `Application Support` > `/Users/k/Library/Application Support/pipx/venvs/ansible/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible`; `/Users/k/Library/Application Support/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/python`.

Comment: hm... how to fix it then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [known issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/82535) caused by space in path:

```
ansible python module location = /Users/k/Library/Application Support/pipx/venvs/ansible/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
```

As a [workaround](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/issues/530#issuecomment-1954632466):

1. Uninstall Ansible `pipx uninstall ansible`
2. Set the environment variable `PIPX_HOME` to path without space. To do this, add the following line to the file `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PIPX_HOME=$HOME/Library/pipx
```

Make sure if path exists `ls $HOME/Library/pipx`. If not, create it `mkdir $HOME/Library/pipx`

3. Apply the change using the `source ~/.bash_profile` command.
4. Install Ansible again `pipx install --include-deps ansible`

Comment: Thanks but I fixed it just by uninstalling ansible and not using pipx annymore.... If  you provide the full solution here where the PIPX_HOME to point and works I can mark your as answer

Comment: Ok, I added the update you asked for